# useContext() react hook doesn't return the correct value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I wrap my Home component in the following layout:

```js
export const DataContext = React.createContext({});

const Layout: React.FunctionComponent = (props) => {
  const data = {title: "abc", description: "def"};
  
  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={data}>
        {props.children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I would like to use useContext hook in my Home component, but it returns an empty object:

```js
const Home: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const content = React.useContext(DataContext);

  return (
    <Layout>
       // content data goes here
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

I suspected that this is because I define context variable outside of Layout wrapper, which contains context provider, so it falls back to the default value of the context that I defined (an empty object). However, even if I console log the useContext hook inside the layout provider, it also returns an empty object:

```js
const Home: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const content = React.useContext(DataContext);

  return (
    <Layout>
      {console.log(React.useContext(DataContext))}
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Please make those Stack Snippets **runnable** ([here's how](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/)), or just use code blocks. Don't use Stack Snippets as code blocks.

Answer (score 12):

`useContext` will get the `value` from the `Provider` closest to it up the tree. Your `Layout` is inside `Home`, which will make the `Provider` below it in the tree.

You could make `Home` a child to `Layout` instead to see it working.

**Example**

```js
const DataContext = React.createContext({});

const Layout = props => {
  const data = { title: "abc", description: "def" };

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={data}>{props.children}</DataContext.Provider>
  );
};

const Home = () => {
  const content = React.useContext(DataContext);

  return <div>{JSON.stringify(content)}</div>;
};

function App() {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <Home />
    </Layout>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Hypothesis that useContext provides an empty object when used outside of Layout is indeed correct. If there is no `Provider` in the hierarchy then useContext returns the default value provided to `React.createContext`

Also you can only use `React hooks` at the start of functional components and not within rendering. So if you write your code like below you will be able to correctly log context value

```
const Content: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
   const content = React.useContext(DataContext);
   console.log(content);
   return (
      <div>Content</div>
   )
}
const Home: React.FunctionComponent = () => {

  return (
    <Layout>
      <Content />
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/3rmkjm5vjq)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was facing same kind of issue and after a lot of googling I find out that whenever our page refreshes it set the context value to its default.

So if you are using  tag or somthing like that for navigation or something which refreshes the page then use  tag from react-router-dom or  instead.

This works for me.